# Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details

Tags: react-native

I am developing a react-native app. I work on it everyday, but today, I launch the command "react-native run-android" and I get this message:

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-billing'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-billing:_debugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1.
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.jar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/Desktop/React Native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/Desktop/React Native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.jar
        Required by:
            AwesomeProject:react-native-billing:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.42.3-atlassian-1
      > Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1.
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/.m2/repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/.m2/repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.jar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/Desktop/React Native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/Desktop/React Native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/25.3.1/recyclerview-v7-25.3.1.jar
        Required by:
            AwesomeProject:react-native-billing:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.42.3-atlassian-1
      > Could not find com.atlassian.mobile.video:okhttp-ws-compat:3.7.0-atlassian1.
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.jar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/Desktop/React Native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/Desktop/React Native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.jar
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.pom
            file:/C:/Users/xrobot/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/atlassian/mobile/video/okhttp-ws-compat/3.7.0-atlassian1/okhttp-ws-compat-3.7.0-atlassian1.jar
        Required by:
            AwesomeProject:react-native-billing:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.42.3-atlassian-1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 35.786 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Why ?

Comment: Have you try run app from android studio? I think it's version issue

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `adb devices`
   => List of devices: *emulator-5554*
2. `react-native run-android --deviceId emulator-5554`

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to @user7425896

1. adb devices => List of devices: eb9c9bbc
2. Delete Android and iOS folders from the project
3. Run 'react-native eject', this will re-add the platforms
4. react-native run-android --deviceId eb9c9bbc

Tested on Windows

Note: in some cases, you might have to do the following:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

Answer (score -1):

are you running behhind proxy or firewall? if so try adding proxy configurations into your .gradle file... basically it means gradle is unable to find a required  lib for your projectt to build properly

Comment: No proxy/firewall. The app worked perfectly 2 days ago, now it doesn't work anymore and run-android command show me that message.

Comment: well it looks like you're missing some required dependencies for building your project such as 'recycler view' (can be installed via android studio / sdk manager) & atlassian - maybe try updating your build tools & support repository...?